# How to do it navigationBarOrientation and navigationBarMode in Bing Maps V8

Tags: bing-maps

I am using the next code but can not make it work for me.
where it bug location

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>loadMapSyncHTML</title>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?branch=release'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function loadMapScenario() {
            var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('divActivityQueryMapView'), {
            credentials: '',
            navigationBarMode: navigationBarMode.compact
            center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(51.50632, -0.12714)
            });
            map.setOptions({
            maxZoom: 12,
            minZoom: 5,
            navigationBarOrientation:horizontal             
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload='loadMapScenario();'>
    <div id='printoutPanel'></div>               
    <div id='divActivityQueryMapView' style='width: 800px; height: 900px;'></div>
</body>
```

And tried in the map parameters and in the map constructor but it does not work

Comment: What does "does not work" actually mean. Please read how to post a proper, useful question.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example:

```
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
    credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key',
    navigationBarMode: Microsoft.Maps.NavigationBarMode.minified,
    navigationBarOrientation: Microsoft.Maps.NavigationBarOrientation.horizontal
});
```

Note that the compact navigation bar does not support setting the orientation at this time.